# How to update an MSI in a remote macine

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installation

I created an msi that that installs my application. Now i want to do an update the msi. I used

`msiexec /fvomus "application.msi"`

This showed no error. But when when i try to update an application in remote machine it shows the below error

> The installation package couldn't be opened. Contact the Application
>   vendor to verify this is a valid Windows installer

I used the below command for remote installation

msiexec /fvomus "//server/c$/Program Files/path_to_my_application/1.msi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to update a product you've installed from an MSI package:

1. msiexec /f... does not update anything. The /f means that it's a repair, and that means to check that the currently installed product is correct. If you're using WiX and you want to upgrade an installed product then the MajorUpgrade element is the simplest and most reliable approach.
2. That error message is too generic to provide a simple answer. It may be that the MSI file is already open in another app, or you don't have the privilege to access that file (IMO the most likely explanation).